# MYQSL, get unique row if the query match with multiple conditions for the same column/property

Tags: mysql, database, row

I tried many times and queries, im done with this, please help me, i have the following table.

```js
ID   Name             event                transaction_number
--------------------------------------------------------
118  John            paymentSend                   001
118  John            paymentFailed                 002
118  John            paymentInProcess              003
118  John            notPaid                       004
118  John            paymentStucked                005
118  John            paymentSuccess                006
```

I want to know if "John", paid the amount, i can easily use "paymentSuccess", but also i want to know
if payment is done or failed, i have "paymentFailed" existent record, so i want to ask if
"paymentFailed" && "paymentSuccess" doesnot exists,  so i need to query the same column, something like

```
SELECT * 
  from users 
 where event = "paymentFailed" 
   AND event != "paymentSuccess"
```

and get 1 record if payment is failed and success doesn't exists, i want to ask for all users, thanks in advance.

1.- Show failed if success doesn't exists

2.- show empty if both conditions doesn't match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find all users not having payment failed and payment success, we can use aggregation:

```sql
SELECT ID, Name
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID, Name
HAVING SUM(event = 'paymentSuccess') = 0 AND SUM(event = 'paymentFailed') > 0;
```

Comment: Not works as expected, maybe i just write wrong.

I can query failed payments, but i don't want to get results if there are existent "paymentSuccess" records, because the paymentSuccess flag is when a payment is done, so the failed is not needed, i want two conditions:

1.- Payment failed
2.- Payment success is not present

if the 2 conditions are met, ishould see the failed.

Btw thank you  for your quickly answer.

Comment: You probably didn't get your logic across.  What is your logic?

Comment: What happens is that for a transaction there are events, Failed, Success, and others, but it is requested to know how many payments "are pending or failed", so I must search the database for those that are "Failed", but at the same time once they are not "success"

Comment: Check my slight edit above.  Now it finds those transactions which are failed, but not success.

Comment: Still showing the record, i think should be empty results because doesn't match both conditions

Comment: @YoshioHPalacios I won't make any further edits, because your sample data does not agree with what you are saying the comments.  What you said in the comments it that you want transactions which a) do _not_ have failed, and b) which _do_ have success.  My answer does this; your example data is the problem.

Comment: oh sorry, in the example it says that "the record must be shown, if it is failed and the success" does not exist ", sorry I shouldn't have put the success in the table,